# z jump around equivalent for editing files?

Tags: shell, vim, vi, neovim

Is there an equivalent to z jump around for opening most edited files with a terminal editor like vim in my case? I have browsed GitHub but couldn't find anything.

Comment: What even is "z jump around"?

Comment: It probably means https://github.com/rupa/z, which tracks the most used directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vim remembers recently opened files by `v:oldfiles` which is loaded from `~/.viminfo` file.

---

##### Custom completion

With [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) and [custom-fuzzy-completion](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#custom-fuzzy-completion), we can search for file from history more naturally, like `vim **<TAB>` with follows

```
# Custom fuzzy completion for "vim" command
#   e.g. vim **<TAB>
_fzf_complete_vim() {
  _fzf_complete --multi --reverse --prompt="vim> " -- "$@" < <(
      cat ~/.viminfo | grep '^>' | sed 's/^> //'
  )
}
```

In `zsh` you're good to go. In `bash`, you have to manually call the`complete` command.

```
[ -n "$BASH" ] && complete -F _fzf_complete_vim -o default -o bashdefault vim
```

> As the documentation says, the custom completion API is experimental and subject to change.

---

##### The previous answer using a new command

For instance, we can read history from it and search for file using [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf) as follows

```sh
#!/bin/bash

file=$(cat ~/.viminfo | grep '^>' | sed 's/^> //' | fzf)
file=${file/#\~/$HOME}
if [ ! -z "$file" ]; then
  vim $file
fi
```

- Read .viminfo. Get the opened file list. Pass it to `fzf`
- Replace `~` with `$HOME` (Vim doesn't expand `~` in the file argument)
- Open the file if not empty

You can save it as `vim-history.sh` and run it in the terminal.

Comment: I was looking for a more 'intelligent' way, like z does with ranking but it's a pretty good workaround thanks!

Comment: I agree it's better to start with the origin vim. I've added a new way using fzf custom completion. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Oh, I guess I missed the point of ranking which may consider frequency and stuff.

Comment: I ended up extending your first script to match z's behavior more closely (chooses the best file alone, so the most recent match in this case).

```lang-bash
#!/bin/bash

nvim -es -c 'redir! > ~/.cache/nvim/rof | oldfiles | redir END | q!'
files=$(sed -r 's/^[0-9]+: //g' ~/.cache/nvim/rof | grep '^/')
file=$(echo $files | sed 's/ \//\n\//g' | fzf -1 -0 -f "$@" | awk 'NR==1{print}')
if [ ! -z "$file" ]; then
    if [ ! -z "$EDITOR" ]; then
        edit=$EDITOR
    else
        edit='nvim'
    fi
    $edit $file
fi
```
I lied I'm actually on nvim :3

Thanks for your insight!